# Serial communication using lisp on windows

Tags: windows, serial-port, lisp

I have opened both ports indicated with (19200 8-N-1) specifications.

Using the software "virtual COM port", I connected COM8 and COM9 via NULL-modem.

This is my Lisp code:

```
(require "serial-port")
(require "com")

(setf ser-port
      (serial-port:open-serial-port "COM8" :baud-rate 19200
                                    :data-bits 8 :stop-bits 1 :parity :none))

(with-open-file (com8 “COM8”
                      :direction :output
                      :element-type 'unsigned-byte)
  (write-byte 65 com8))
```

I did not get any communication at COM9, however.

When I tried sending data from MATLAB (enabling COM8 in MATLAB) to COM9, I was sucessful.

Please, any suggestions?

Comment: You have invalid ("unicode") quote marks around `COM8` in the `with-open-file` form.

Comment: Still it is not working .. can u send changed code?

Comment: Lisp works 6.1 ...........